# Are there any htaccess or allow-files to enable Cross Site Scripting? Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, same-origin-policy

I need to send and load JSON data to and from a PHP script on a different domain and while the variables were passed, nothing is returned.

domain1.com/display.php (has Jquery $post() routine to send and load data)  to
domain2.com/data.php (php script outputs JSON data) <-- this receives data, but response is not sent to requesting script.

Of course this is due to browser security restricting cross site scripting stuffs.

I've read a bit about JSONP but that's just another extra step.

I remember when I used to do FLASH, i would just uload a policy file to the server on a different domain where I would load data from and everything would just work.

Is there anything like that for JavaScript? if not, WHY the HECK not?! Seems to me like it's a legit, hassle free solution, that's just about as secure as JSONP method, or even more so.

Regards

Comment: No, there is no way to influence this by a setting on a server. You either have to download the script from the domain, you'll be querying or you have to create a PHP (or any other server side script), that will relay the request to other domain for you.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, though it's unfortunate news..
I have no problem w/ PHP but this time it's JS function that needs to load the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say "it's Javascript that needs to load the data", I gather this is running in some browser. In this case, the browser is enforcing security, as fas as I know, and fiddling with the server( script)s will not help.

Chrome has a command-line option to turn off XS security (--disable-web-security), and Firefox has a setting in about:config (I think, can't find it right now... sorry).

But I guess there's reason to these security settings in the first place... ;-)

Comment: thanks. perhaps if i get desperate I'll turn off web-security feature in the browser for my intranet applications .. lol

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load it on the client? Using PHP+cURL it should be no problem on the server side. If you really need to load cross domain content on the client side you could use the [Cross Domain jQuery plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) (uses YQL internally)

Comment: thanks but that's still another process / dependency. I'm trying to avoid more complications, trying to keep things bare/simple.